# What is the most common version control software for Windows?

Tags: windows, version-control

Coming from a UNIX background, with some knowledge of CVS and git, I have gotten my Windows development skills up in just about every area. But I still have no idea if there is a single VCS that Windows devs "have" to know.

Is there one used above all others?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The makers of [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/) used to do a survey every year of their (mostly Windows-based) customers. I can't find anything more recent than [their 2008 survey](http://www.finalbuilder.com/Resources/Blogs/tabid/77/EntryId/264/Top-10-Version-Control-Systems.aspx), but here's what it looked like then.

[image]

As you can see, there isn't just one you have to know. However, you'd be a fool not to familiarize yourself with Subverion and Sourcesafe.

If I were to predict how it has changed since then, I'd guess that Subversion has added users, SourceSafe has lost a bit of ground to Team Foundation, and that Git now shows up, but with only minor numbers.

Comment: One quick public service announcement: Despite what this chart may seem to indicate, SourceSafe is in no way an acceptable choice and should not be used under any circumstances (except perhaps if the only other option is "no VCS at all" and even then I'm not sure).

Comment: CVS will slowly lose numbers, and will not gain.  There's no point in using CVS over SVN, and it's easy to go from CVS to SVN.

Comment: I'm in violent **agreement** with both David and camccann.

Answer (score 3):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (svn) has tight integration with explorer, and most devs I know that run Windows and use subversion also use Tortoise.

Answer (score 2):

Not really specific to Windows I think, but Subversion (SVN) is a must.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TortioseSVN runs quite well on windows. There's also a Tortoise for git! Though I am not too sure if it's as easy as its SVN cousin.

https://tortoisegit.org/

Comment: It's not. I've heard of a number of compatibility issues, but then again, it seems like Tortoise fixes a huge gaping security issue or memory leak with every minor release, so there's never telling what the state of the product truly is.

Comment: It's almost the same UI.  But I haven't seen how to do 'git rebase -i' from that UI, which is half the reason to use git.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, is SVN.

For free:

CVS is pretty much dead.

[Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) has the best integration with windows ([explorer](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), [visual studio](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), [eclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), command line, WebDAV, etc...) it also has GUI's for other [platforms](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/).

With Git you're relegated to use the command line exclusively.

Not Free:
Perforce is okay, but whatever you do, don't use Visual Sourcesafe and risk your entire repository getting corrupted at some point in time and not realizing it until much later.

Comment: Have to disagree about Git. I use Git on Windows whenever I get a chance, and almost never use the command-line on it. Git-gui rocks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the same types of source control that you use on UNIX may also be used on windows. There are certainly ones to avoid on windows - [VSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Before DVCS, all the cool kids used SVN; everyone else used VSS or TFS.

DVCS is turning into an interesting competition as Git clearly has the edge in functionality but Mercurial has the edge in Windows integration.  Poor Bazaar doesn't seem to be getting a look in.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN ties into VS as well and uses TortoiseSVN for a backend.  It's $50 per license iirc.  Works pretty well.  If you're looking for a good tie-in with Visual Studio also check out AnkSVN.

Answer (score 0):

We use msys-git quite successfully on windows.  The GUI tools are not great.  I use the command-line and it works fine.  My colleagues use git-extensions which integrate into visual studio.  It seems to work ok.

The other option to me would be SVN.  It has great windows support.

Comment: Not a particularly relevant answer, but I would like to agree that msys-git works just fine on Windows. I personally like the GUI tools too. I never even bothered to learn the command-line commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree: Subversion. But I an quite sure, it will be succeeded by git some day.